# Invoking method defined in object initiated in other class main method

Tags: java

I have 2 classes. Is it possible to set gui object's switchingPanel variable, using gui's setSwitchingPanel method? I know i can't invoke this method from other class in easy way. Is there any way to invoke this metod in AddPatientPanel.class without making JPanels variables and this method as static? I am a beginner, but I have read to avoid anything static.

GUI.class

```
public class GUI
{
    private JPanel switchingPanel;
    private JPanelA panel1 = new JPanelA();
    private JPanelB panel2 = new JPanelB();
    private AddPatientPanel addPatientPanel = new AddPatientPanel();

    public GUI() 
    {
        //Constructor
    }

    public void setSwitchingPanel(JPanel panel)
    {
        switchingPanel = panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                // Invoking GUI constructor
                GUI gui = new GUI();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

AddPatientPanel.class

```
public class AddPatientPanel extends JPanel
{
   public AddPatientPanel()
   {
       //Constructor
   }

   public void myMethod()
   {
        gui.setSwitchingPanel(JPanel panel2) //not working for sure, but i want do something similar to it
   }
}
```

To explain what I need:
In GUI.class i'm creating instances of other classes (which extends JPanel, eg. AddPatientsPanel, AddEmployeePanel, ShowSchedulePanel). I don't want to create another instance of the same panel class to avoid clearing fields in it when the user is changing view (I'm removing old JPanel from frame, and add the new one in it's place). For JMenu, JToolBar shortcuts all is working fine.

But the button in one of this panel classes (for example in AddPatientPanel) have to do the same (change switchingPanel variable and reload the view in frame).

Is it good practise to make GUI classes (classes which extends JPanel) static in this case? I'm trying to avoid it, but maybe unnecessarily?

Comment: Can you not pass in the gui instance to your AddPatientPanel class?

Comment: I added explanation in my post. If i will do this, i'll create a new instance of each class which extends JPanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a method from another class, you have three options:

1. Make the method static and call `GUI.setSwitchingPanel`. You can easily google the advantages and disadvantages of static methods to find out, if this is suitable for you.
2. Create a new instance of the class and call the method (not suitable in your case):

   ```
   GUI gui = new GUI();
   gui.setSetSwitchingPanel();
   ```
3. Pass a reference to the other object and call the method. This does not create a new instance of the class!

   ```
   public class AddPatientPanel extends JPanel
   {
       private GUI gui;

       public AddPatientPanel(GUI gui)
       {
           this.gui = gui;
       }

       public void myMethod()
       {
           gui.setSwitchingPanel(JPanel panel2) 
       }
   }
   ```

   Create the AddPatientPanel in GUI with `new AddPatientPanel(this)`.

These are all the options that you have got, there are no other possibilites.

Comment: I changed my project to MVC project. The option nr 3. was usefull there. After reading some stuff, it's usually best way in my opinion :). Thanks.